# Google Spreadsheet - Populate a cell based off different cells content, and use a third cells value

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

Is it possible to fill a cell with data from another cell based off the content of a different cell? I have a drop down menu in one cell, and when I select something from that menu, I would like the cell next to it to search a database on that sheet that the drop down is based off of. it has a second row with different values I would like to appear in the next column. I think about it, and it should seem easy, but I'm having troubles explaining it.

Comment: You might want to mention *how* you want to go about this. Are you using the API? Are you trying to just do it within the spreadsheet with formulas? Can you give data examples? You need to give more info for anyone to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `VLOOKUP()` to search the list based on the dropdown cell value. [Ref](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093318)